# Python Tweepy API Iteration

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```
    if('RT' in tweet.text):
        #HERE.
    else:
        status = api.get_status(tweet.id)

        print(tweet.text)
        print(tweet.id)


    extra code down here i do not want to execute
```

I want to iterate through each tweet in my feed, if it is a retweet skip over it and continue the iteration. I used pass, but that seems to continue to execute the code after the if statement. I want it to just stop executing the code and go to the next object it has to iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In for loops, the `continue` keyword can be used to do what you want.  `continue` means go directly to the next iteration of the loop.

```
if ('RT' in tweet.text):
    continue
else:
    status = api.get_status(tweet.id)

    print(tweet.text)
    print(tweet.id)
```

Comment: Oh I see, I thought it meant it just continued on with the code. Thanks very much, I misunderstood its meaning.

Comment: no problem!  the syntax of `break`, `continue`, and `pass` are pretty consistent among languages, so once you get a good handle on them it'll be easy from then on.